# Request emitter doesn't emit 'end' in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have situation where the request emitter does emit 'data' event but not the 'end' event. I am not sure how to troubleshoot. How would you?

```
var Review = require('../lib/review')
    , qs = require('querystring');

exports.processReview = function(req, res){
        var body = '';
        req.setEncoding('utf8');
        req.on('data', function(chunk){body += chunk});
        req.on('end', function(){
            console.log('got here: ' + body);
            var obj = qs.parse(body);
            var review = new Review({
                title: obj.param('title'),
                content: obj.param('content'),
                submittedBy: obj.param('submittedBy'),
                recommendedFor: obj.param('recommendedFor')
            });
            console.log('New Review: ' + JSON.stringify(review));
            res.end('Ok\n');
        });
        res.end('Ok\n');
        console.log('_________end______' + body);
    };

    exports.displayForm = function(req, res){
        var html = '<html><head><title>some head</title></head><body><h1>Review Form</h1>'
            + '<form method="post" action="/process/review" >'
            + '<p>Title: <input type="text" name="title" /></p>'
            + '<p>Content: <input type="text" name="content" /></p>'
            + '<p>Nickname: <input type="text" name="submittedBy" /></p>'
            + '<p>Recommended for: <input type="text" name="recommendedFor" /></p>'
            + '<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Review" /></p>'
            + '</form></body></html>';
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(html));
        res.end(html);
    };
```

How would you go and troubleshoot this? and what is the problem? Thank You

Comment: If you're using express, you're making things a lot more difficult than they need to be here.

Comment: Thank you nubers1311407. To some degree, I am aware of it. I am in learning mode and I am doing with purpose of better understanding between native vs express and other aspects. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using express, and `bodyParser` or any similar middleware, then `end` will have already been emitted before it reaches your handler.

But like I said in the comment, if you're using express, you're also making things way too hard on yourself.  You shouldn't *need* to worry about `end` in this situation.  Let the middleware take care of parsing the body.

[And by using `res.send`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L80), you can let express take care of other common tasks as well.  `send` is basically a wrapper around [node's `end`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding).  To name a few things, it:

- accepts HTTP status, body, or both as arguments
- converts objects to json responses
- sets the content-length and other headers
- calculates and sets etag
- sends 304 for requests that hit a fresh cache
- sends head responses for bodiless sends

Your handlers could be written something like:

```
var Review = require('../lib/review');

exports.processReview = function(req, res){
  // the bodyParser (if it is in fact already a middleware) will have parsed
  // the request body already into `req.body`
  var review = new Review({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    submittedBy: req.body.submittedBy,
    recommendedFor: req.body.recommendedFor
  });
  console.log('New Review: ' + JSON.stringify(review));
  // here you'd probably save your view before sending.
  res.send(200);
};

exports.displayForm = function(req, res){
  // here you could keep your html in a template (e.g. /views/form.html), then:
  // res.render("form");

  // but even without doing that, express handles setting the content-type
  // and body length, like so:
  var html = '<html><head><title>some head</title></head><body><h1>Review Form</h1>'
    + '<form method="post" action="/process/review" >'
    + '<p>Title: <input type="text" name="title" /></p>'
    + '<p>Content: <input type="text" name="content" /></p>'
    + '<p>Nickname: <input type="text" name="submittedBy" /></p>'
    + '<p>Recommended for: <input type="text" name="recommendedFor" /></p>'
    + '<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Review" /></p>'
    + '</form></body></html>';
  res.send(html);
};
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. At the high level, what are the main differences between .end() and .send() methods in Express? The .end(), it doesn't set the headers, correct?...

Comment: Edited with some notes on `send`.  It's more or less a wrapper around [end](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) that handles common tasks like setting content type and length.

Answer (score 1):

In your `processReview` function, you are ending the response for every request.

```
    res.end('Ok\n'); // end response
    console.log('_________end______' + body);
```

The request is finished processing on `res.end` and no more events are listened/processed anymore. Since you execute `res.end` unconditionally it does not reach the event handler of `end` for the request.

Comment: Thank You user568109. I plugged in the unconditional res.end('ok\n') in there because the client request was hanging. The debugging tool confirmed that we are not getting the 'end' event from request stream.  p.s.Why are you and numbers1311xxx using such a strange usernames?... probably not of my business:)